# Correct way to maintain a One to many relation with fixed count of children rows?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core

I am modeling a common one to many relation between an Authors table and a Books table.

By convention, an Author can have 30 books assigned as a maximum. So, when an author gets its max number of books and another one want to be assigned to the same author, I must delelete oldest one and add new one.

I could do the obvious operation of delete de oldest book and add the new one to keep the 30 books limit but I wonder if it is a more direct way to do this or if this is common practice in this situation.

Comment: It's a little unusual to impose such limits on data storage (as opposed to data retrieval), so I suspect that there isn't a common practice; I think it depends a bit on what the user experience should  be like, and whether a user might want to decide which entry/ies gets over-written.

Comment: One idea is to populate the table with 30 rows for each author, and then only allow UPDATEs on rows when ordered by 'blank' then date.

Comment: Another, idea table has one record_deleted column with one/zero value, if each author row hit the 30 row it must update that column,fetch 30 rows with where clause on record_deleted column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,author_id INT NOT NULL,book VARCHAR(50) NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table (author_id) VALUES (1),(1),(1);

UPDATE my_table SET book = 'my first book' WHERE author_id = 1 ORDER BY book,id LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-----------+---------------+
| id | author_id | book          |
+----+-----------+---------------+
|  1 |         1 | my first book |
|  2 |         1 | NULL          |
|  3 |         1 | NULL          |
+----+-----------+---------------+

UPDATE my_table SET book = 'my second book' WHERE author_id = 1 ORDER BY book,id LIMIT 1;

UPDATE my_table SET book = 'my third book' WHERE author_id = 1 ORDER BY book,id LIMIT 1;

UPDATE my_table SET book = 'my fourth book' WHERE author_id = 1 ORDER BY book,id LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-----------+----------------+
| id | author_id | book           |
+----+-----------+----------------+
|  1 |         1 | my fourth book |
|  2 |         1 | my second book |
|  3 |         1 | my third book  |
+----+-----------+----------------+
```

Oh, forgot to add the timestamp (or a mechanism for editing the id) - :-$, but hopefully you get the idea; I'll edit it if I have a minute

Comment: Ok, thats something that at lists limits somehow it. I just have to remember to use Update :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don´t want to insert 30 datasets per author in advance, you can create a stored procedure which counts the authors first and if there are less than 30 you do an insert, else you update the author like 'Strawberry' suggests.
If you access the db via repositories, you can handle it the same way in a repo - method.